# Defining an offset when using php array_search / array_column to find a value (eg ignore 1 matching result, find the next)

Tags: php, arrays

I have two main tables for rail schedules, which are

- **Timetabled visits** - a list of *planned* call times for services
- **Actual visits** - contains a list of realtime reports for visits , ie the actual visit times.

Timetabled visits, containing a list of locations being called at, can have the same location more than once 
*(in the event that the service goes into a terminus station to reverse, passing one or more of the previously passed locations on the way back out)*

A column in the `timetabled visits` table, contains an instance count, which will be *null* unless the service has passed this location earlier in the timetable, in which case the value of this "visit instance" column would be 2 , because it is the second visit.

Now what I am doing is I am displaying a list of the visits, their planned call times, and their actual call times.

The way I am doing this is I am storing all of the planned calls and call times into an array such as that below.
(This is the result of a mysqli prepared query, shortly after the results have been binded to a variable.

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
        $reports[$count]['tiploc_code'] = $tiploc_code;
        $reports[$count]['stanox'] = $stanox;
        $reports[$count]['fn'] = $fn;
        $reports[$count]['arrival'] = $arrival;
        $reports[$count]['departure'] = $departure;
        $reports[$count]['pass'] = $pass;
        $count = $count + 1;
}
```

Then im doing another query to select the realtime performances for the above. This realtime performance table does have different column names.

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
        $call[$calls]['tps'] = $tps;
        $call[$calls]['stanox'] = $loc_stanox;
        $call[$calls]['next'] = $next_stanox;
        $call[$calls]['actual'] = $actual;

        $calls = $calls + 1;
}
```

Now im using the array search feature of PHP.

Note that this is inside a while loop for the html table which I am displaying the visits. For each visit, I am populating the first part of the array_search with "stanox" - a unique number which is the location ID.
Then in array_column im looking up the realtime call which has the same location ID as in $reports ID, thereby, getting the realtime data for that location visit.

```
$search_index = array_search($reports[$index]['stanox'], array_column($call, 'stanox'));
```

Now in the html table, show the actual call time.

```
 $actual         = $call[$newid]['actual'];
echo $actual;
```

---

My problem?

Well as mentioned earlier, the same location can be called at twice. 
So instead, what I want to do is use the "visit instance" field, as an offset.
If this is the second location call, I want to ignore the first, and show only the most recent call time based on instance. Likewise, if its the third time it has visited this location, I need to ignore the first 2 reports.

Is this possible?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: array_search doesn’t know any offset parameter or something like that. I think you should maybe rather change how you keep your data in the first place. If whatever `stanox` is, is the key by which you logically “group” those records, then maybe you should use that as key on the _first_ array level already, and then group the different timed events under that, in an array.

Comment: I would pull all the visit_instance fields for the location you're looking for into an array, and then do a `max`:  `$latestvalue = max($visits)`